# Creating Application Display Template for RSS Reader in Liferay DXP 7

Tags: liferay, rss-reader

I want to create a custom application display template for a couple of RSS Publisher portlets I have on one of our pages and I have two questions:

1) Is there a way to display more than 9 RSS entries in an RSS feed?

2) I want to loop through the entries, and create a list of the entries:

```
<ul>
{loop this for each entry}
<li><a href="<theUrl>"><theTitle></a></li>
{end loop}
</ul>
```

Can someone tell me how to accomplish this or where can I find documentation on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

The stock ADTs are contained in Liferay and you can use them as the basis for your own work.

Use the site selector to navigate to the "Global" scope, where you'll find the Application Display Templates that are available. Open and inspect them. Copy the code, create new ones using this example. Then configure your portlet to use the newly created template.